# Relation between wireless network's frequency, speed, and range?

Tags: wireless-networking

Wireless network standards:

> 802.11a
>
> This definition provides wireless access on the 5 GHz band. It offers
>   speeds of up to 54 MBps, but has not caught on, perhaps due to
>   relatively higher priced equipment and short range.
>
> 802.11b
>
> This is still the standard to which most people refer when talking
>   about wireless networking. It establishes 11 MBps speeds on the 2.4
>   GHz band, and can have a range extending more than 500 meters.

Is there relation between a wireless network's frequency, speed, and range?

Is their relation a trade-off one?
Is it true that the higher the frequency, the higher the speed, and the smaller the range?

What factors determine a wireless network's frequency, speed, and range?

Thanks.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Most of your questions can be answered by just reading the 802.11 specification.  Why are you asking about 802.11a and 802.11b which hasn't been used in years for obvious reasons.  802.11a was 5 Ghz and 802.11b was 2.4 ghz.

Comment: Also, network speeds are measured in Mbps (Megabits per second) and not MBps (Megabytes per second)...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a relationship, and yes, there are tradeoffs. Higher frequency signals degrade over shorter distances, but can carry data more quickly. In the end, the thing you should be worried about however is which specification you choose to use; it has all the parameters built in. you just select a wireless-N router and wireless-N devices, and let it worry about the other factors.

Just because a spec uses a 5GHz carrier, does not necessarily mean that it will be faster. Wireless uses an analog media to carrier analog signals, so just like with wires, it is important for the specification to "square wave" (make approximations that are predictable and clearly defined) the different parameters of the connection in order to use it for digital transmission. So, once again, you are worried about the specification, not the underlying characteristics of the transport operations. For instance, even if 5GHz can theoretically carry data faster over short distances, a dual-band spec like N will carry the data at a constant rate, regardless of the band it is operating in. The spec rules all.

Environmentally, the only thing you need worry about are propagation and interference. if you have a lot of interference on the 2.4Ghz spectrum, then perhaps 5GHz is the right choice for you. If your walls a dense plaster or metal rather than light 2x4's and sheetrock, or you have power generation equipment nearby that interfers with wireless signals, then perhaps 2.4GHz is better.

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. (1) My router is linksys WRT54GL. Its options for channel are 1 (2.412GHz) to 11 (2.462GHz). Does it mean that the router will not create a wireless network with 5GHz? (2) My router supports "Mixed", "B-only" and "G-only" network mode. Is 5GHz only supported by 802.11a, not by 802.11b or 802.11g?

Comment: 5GHz is supported by A, N, and the new one (I forget what its letter is). B/G only operate at 2.4GHz, and if an N router is configured for B/G/N it will only operate in 2.4GHz. Most routers can only operate at one frequency for all connections, so if you allow a 2.4GHz spec on your network, then it has to run everything at 2.4. I know they made them for a number of years, but a WRT54GL is ancient. I have to recommend you get something from this decade.

Comment: " if an N router is configured for B/G/N it will only operate in 2.4GHz. Most routers can only operate at one frequency for all connections, so if you allow a 2.4GHz spec on your network, then it has to run everything at 2.4." My router is G router (supports G, B and their mix). Its channel options vary from channel 1 (2.412GHz) to 11 (2.462GHz), doesn't it not just operate on one frequency?

Comment: yes, both B and G are 2.4GHz band  technologies.

Comment: Do you call  the freq range from 2.412GHz to 2.462GHz (offered as channel options in my router) "a 2.4GHz spec"?

Comment: In common parlance, it is a "Band" of frequencies around 2.4GHz. The specs are A/B/G/N. The Band is then broken down into "channels", or "sub-bands". The radios in a wifi device can work on any channel within the 2.4GHz band, so they are said to be 2.4GHz devices, implementing whatever spec. All the specs imply a single band, except N, and the new prototypical one, which can be set to use either 2.4GHz or 5GHz bands (but not usually both).